# Root aggregate reference problem

Tags: domain-driven-design

Can an entity inside aggregate which is not root can hold reference to root aggregate. Or is root aggregate can only hold reference to its child entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An entity within an aggregate can hold a reference to the aggregate root.

Entities within an aggregate may also hold references to other, external aggregate roots.

External objects may NOT hold a reference to an entity that is internal to the aggregate.  External objects must reference the aggregate root only, no internal objects.

Only aggregates should be returned from queries/repositories.

An aggregate should be created as an entire set, typically using a factory.

Comment: Can I create aggregate using IOC, I mean where i can use IOC in ddd. To create objects in service layer in place of factory .

Comment: Complicated question.  Services are source of activity in applications and so are often the source of actions that ultimately result in object creation.  You must distinguish the request from the mechanics and responsibility for creating objects, i.e the actual construction code itself. Nothing is more intimate or detailed than the knowledge of domain object creation, and that is part of the domain model.  So while services may call for object creation, actually putting the creation code in the service layer is leaking domain layer knowledge and creating a very tightly coupled service layer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "External Objects" would a ViewModel in the MVVM paradigm be considered an "External Object" or are you more specifically referring to objects within the Domain Layer?